# Save cropped pdf image from R imagemagick to a new pdf

Tags: r, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using `R` with imagemagick to crop some borders from a pdf file. I'm executing the following commands:

```
library(magick)

pdf_total <- image_read_pdf(path =  "file1.pdf")
pdf_cropped <- image_crop(pdf_total,"3000x1500")
```

After this process I have a perfect cropped file, but my problem occurs when I try to save the file to a new pdf file. What is the correct procedure to save this converted pdf?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is:

```
library(magick)

pdf_total <- image_read_pdf(path =  "file1.pdf")
pdf_cropped <- image_crop(pdf_total,"3000x1500")


for(i in seq(1,length(pdf_cropped))){

     plot(pdf_cropped[i])

}

dev.off()
```

In this case I made a for loop to save all the pages, if you pass `plot(pdf_cropped)` the result is a pdf with a single page (first picture).